# Error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException. How fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem with my project. When i brower `http://localhost:8080/user/form` to display UserForm, but occur following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet .jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Male'
>   for locale 'en_US'.
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspSer
>   vletWrapper.java:585)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
>   .java:455)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
>   05)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:801
>   )
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
>   :587)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
>   ava:143)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
>   a:595)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
>   er.java:223)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
>   er.java:1126)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
>   515)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
>   r.java:185)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
>   r.java:1060)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
>   ava:141)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:200)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:75)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMerge
>   dOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView
>   .java:267)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherSe
>   rvlet.java:1217)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResu
>   lt(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
>   erServlet.java:952)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
>   rServlet.java:870)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
>   workServlet.java:961)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
>   et.java:852)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
>   vlet.java:837)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:801
>   )
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
>   :587)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
>   ava:143)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
>   a:577)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
>   er.java:223)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
>   er.java:1126)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
>   515)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
>   r.java:185)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
>   r.java:1060)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
>   ava:141)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
>   extHandlerCollection.java:215)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl
>   ection.java:110)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
>   .java:113)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:509)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:288)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.jav
>   a:240)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java
>   :539)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
>   l.java:620)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool
>   .java:540)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No 
>   message found under code 'Male' for locale 'en_US'.
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageC
>   ontextImpl.java:905)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageCon
>   textImpl.java:834)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.UserForm_jsp._jspService(UserForm_js
>   p.java:444)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
>   .java:432)
>           ... 46 more Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Male'  for locale 'en_US'.
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.j
>   ava:202)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.UserForm_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fm
>   essage_005f0(UserForm_jsp.java:754)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.UserForm_jsp._jspService(UserForm_js
>   p.java:318)

Here file `UserForm.jsp`

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>         
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New User</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2>Please Input User Information</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="User" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userName">UserName</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="passWord">Password</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="passWord"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="passWord" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="birthDay">Birthday</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="birthDay" type = "date"/> </td>

                <td><form:errors path="birthDay"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label>
                <td><form:input path="age" type = "number"/> </td>
                <td><form:errors path="age"></form:errors> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td><form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label></td>
                <td><form:select path="gender">
                        <c:forEach var="temp" items="${allgender}">

                            <form:option value="${temp}">
                                <spring:message code="${temp.gender}"/>
                            </form:option>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </form:select></td>
                <td><form:errors path="gender"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>





            <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form:form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Here file `Gender.java`

```
package edu.java.spring.service.user.model;

public enum Gender {
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female"),
    OTHER("Other");
    private String name;

    private Gender(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender(){
        return this.name;
    }



}
```

Here file `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.java.spring.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>springDAT-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springDAT-service Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springMOTHER-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You're missing some libraries somewhere. Can you post your dependencies?

Comment: @Desorder, i have added file `pom.xml` on my post

Comment: Have you tried using something other than `enum`, which is a Java keyword (and maybe a JSP EL keyword)?

Comment: @JBNizet, i have edited `enum` to `temp`, but occur a new error. i have added on my post

Comment: So, the issue is fixed. You have `<spring:message code="${temp.gender}"/>` in your JSP. the value of ${temp.gender is "Male". So this tries to get a message for the key "Male" in your resource bundle, and there is no such key. The error message tells you that. Have you read it?

Comment: @JBNizet, I have read this error, but really not understand `No message found under code 'Male' for locale 'en_US'`. you can explain to me ???

Comment: Yep, @JBNizet seems to be on track. Can you now post your message bundle?

Comment: @Desorder, i have post full error on my post

Comment: @DatB.Pham Try to replace the `<c:foreach />` tag for `<form:options itemLabel="gender" />`

Comment: @Desorder, i have fixed it with your way, thank more

Comment: I will put as an answer for you to mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to print the value of the `<option>` tag using `<spring:message>` but `<spring:message>` is trying to load the label from a properties file that you don't have.

Try to replace the whole `<c:foreach />` tag for `<form:options itemLabel="gender" />`.